# scannable barcode FONTS for SSRS report which can scan symbols too

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, barcode, ssrs-2012

There are basically two questions I'd like to ask here.

---

I have downloaded few fonts.(code 128, code-128 and free3to9 etc)
 created report
 took textBox
 entered string like `123#123`
 set textbox font to downloaded few fonts.
 In preview,
 everything is fine. But when I try to read/scan generated barcode from preview,
 In some case, it returns other fonts than `123#123`
 In some case, it doesn't scan the font.

So question is, 
 1). In SSRS report can we add scannable font which can scan symbols too and give exact and desire output? 

 If yes how and please let me know working font download link.

2). Only by downloading font and storing it to client and server would give desire out put?

---

I have checked this article which forces you to add `.dll file` and change some `core files`.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/789254/How-to-embed-Barcodes-in-your-SSRS-report

I followed this article and able to get the desired output. I could generate barcode in ssrs report and by exporting it to PDF, I'm able to scan it properly with symbols.

But this approach requires to `copy .dll` to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

I did it and everything works as a charm.

But problem is I don't want to go with this approach as at server end I have to change some `core files` and `copy .dll`. I don't want to take such risk as high risk is associated with it.

so any other alternative way if someone has done it already.

Comment: from my previous experience, i don't generate in SSRS report. Same library i using, but generate barcode from web/windows application and convert to base64String then store to database (nvarchar(max)). SSRS report is able to convert base64String back to image.

Comment: But I don't have any interface or UI for that. I have a `stored procedure` which returns `string` and use that `SP` in SSRS report. Any suggestion?

Comment: i hear another way for barcode is install barcode in Windows Font, so SSRS would be able to display. 
http://www.dafont.com/code-128.font
Anyway, i never tried this please tell me if works xD

Comment: I have already tried it. But the problem is when I scan it , it doesn't show me correct string.

Comment: In some cases it just doesn't scan the barcode !

Comment: u scan it through what device? code 128 usually need a larger width to get correct string from scan result.

Comment: I scan through it mobile.

Comment: code 128 requires check digits and stop start characters, if you are using a font to generate your barcode you'll need to also include these start/stop and check chars in your string. otherwise it just wont read.

Answer (score 2):

For the font, we used Libre_Barcode_128

It needs to be installed for all users on the server running Reporting Services (right click the LibreBarcode128-Regular.ttf file, choose "Install for all users").  Then the reporting services box needs to be restarted (maybe you could just bounce the services, I just rebooted).

Then in the report, I changed the font to that.  It produced barcodes, but those codes were not scannable.  I had to change the field to:

=Code.StringToBarcode(Fields!Id.Value)

Then you right click in the black area around the report designer, and choose "Report Properties".  Go to the Code tab, and paste this:

```
    Public Shared Function StringToBarcode(ByVal value As String) As String
    ' Parameters : a string
    ' Return     : a string which give the bar code when it is displayed with CODE128.TTF font
    '           : an empty string if the supplied parameter is no good
    Dim charPos, minCharPos As Integer
    Dim currentChar, checksum As Integer
    Dim isTableB = True, isValid = True
    Dim returnValue = String.Empty

    If value.Length > 0 Then

        ' Check for valid characters
        For charCount As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
            'currentChar = char.GetNumericValue(value, charPos);
            currentChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(Char.Parse(value.Substring(charCount, 1)))
            If Not (currentChar >= 32 AndAlso currentChar <= 126) Then
                isValid = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ' Barcode is full of ascii characters, we can now process it
        If isValid Then
            charPos = 0
            While charPos < value.Length
                If isTableB Then
                    ' See if interesting to switch to table C
                    ' yes for 4 digits at start or end, else if 6 digits
                    If charPos = 0 OrElse charPos + 4 = value.Length Then
                        minCharPos = 4
                    Else
                        minCharPos = 6
                    End If


                    minCharPos = IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos)

                    If minCharPos < 0 Then
                        ' Choice table C
                        If charPos = 0 Then
                            ' Starting with table C
                            returnValue = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(205).ToString() ' char.ConvertFromUtf32(205);
                        Else
                            ' Switch to table C
                            returnValue = returnValue & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(199).ToString()
                        End If
                        isTableB = False
                    Else
                        If charPos = 0 Then
                            ' Starting with table B
                            returnValue = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(204).ToString() ' char.ConvertFromUtf32(204);
                        End If

                    End If
                End If

                If Not isTableB Then
                    ' We are on table C, try to process 2 digits
                    minCharPos = 2
                    minCharPos = IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos)
                    If minCharPos < 0 Then ' OK for 2 digits, process it
                        currentChar = Integer.Parse(value.Substring(charPos, 2))
                        currentChar = If(currentChar < 95, currentChar + 32, currentChar + 100)
                        returnValue = returnValue & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(currentChar).ToString()
                        charPos += 2
                    Else
                        ' We haven't 2 digits, switch to table B
                        returnValue = returnValue & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(200).ToString()
                        isTableB = True
                    End If
                End If
                If isTableB Then
                    ' Process 1 digit with table B
                    returnValue = returnValue & value.Substring(charPos, 1)
                    charPos += 1
                End If
            End While

            ' Calculation of the checksum
            checksum = 0
            For [loop] As Integer = 0 To returnValue.Length - 1
                currentChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(Char.Parse(returnValue.Substring([loop], 1)))
                currentChar = If(currentChar < 127, currentChar - 32, currentChar - 100)
                If [loop] = 0 Then
                    checksum = currentChar
                Else
                    checksum = (checksum + [loop] * currentChar) Mod 103
                End If
            Next

            ' Calculation of the checksum ASCII code
            checksum = If(checksum < 95, checksum + 32, checksum + 100)
            ' Add the checksum and the STOP
            returnValue = returnValue & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(checksum).ToString() & Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(206).ToString()
        End If
    End If

    Return returnValue
End Function


Private Shared Function IsNumber(ByVal InputValue As String, ByVal CharPos As Integer, ByVal MinCharPos As Integer) As Integer
    ' if the MinCharPos characters from CharPos are numeric, then MinCharPos = -1
    MinCharPos -= 1
    If CharPos + MinCharPos < InputValue.Length Then
        While MinCharPos >= 0
            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(Char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1))) < 48 OrElse Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(Char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1))) > 57 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            MinCharPos -= 1
        End While
    End If
    Return MinCharPos
End Function
```

I believe I based this off of an article here:
[code 128 barcode in c# wrong check digit for one barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288956/code-128-barcode-in-c-sharp-wrong-check-digit-for-one-barcode)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an code 128 encoder coded in T-SQL

You can easily add this new column (encoded text) to your sql result for your report

Then add textbox to your SSRS report and choose code 128 font. and Voilà !

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Reporting].[Code128Encoder]
(
    @TextToEncode NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    
        
    --The following TSQL code will take a character string and perform the encoding 
    --that is necessary to generate a BARCODE 128 formatted string to be used with a BARCODE 128 font.

    -- Define the string of characters that we'll need to pull the reference of
    DECLARE @asciiString NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @asciiString = ' !"#$%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(195) -- 0xC3
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(196) -- 0xC4
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(197) -- 0xC5
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(198) -- 0xC6
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(199) -- 0xC7
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(200) -- 0xC8
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(201) -- 0xC9
    SET @asciiString = @asciiString + CHAR(202) -- 0xCA

    -- Define the stop and start characters
    DECLARE @stopchar CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @startchar CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @spacechar CHAR(1)
    SET @stopchar = CHAR(206) -- 0xCE
    SET @startchar = CHAR(204) -- 0xCC
    SET @spacechar = CHAR(194) -- 0xC2

    -- Define the final holding place of our output string
    DECLARE @finalArray NVARCHAR(255)

    -- Define the variables that we'll need to be using
    DECLARE @checksumTotal INT
    DECLARE @checksum INT
    SET @checksumTotal = 104;
    SET @checksum = 0;

    -- Start building our output
    SET @finalArray = @startchar

    -- Loop through our input variable and start pulling out stuff
    DECLARE @position INT
    DECLARE @thisChar CHAR(1)
    SET @position = 1
    WHILE @position <= LEN(@TextToEncode)
    BEGIN
        SET @thisChar = SUBSTRING(@TextToEncode, @position, 1)
        SET @checksumTotal = @checksumTotal + (@position * (ASCII(@thischar)-32))
        SET @finalArray = @finalArray + @thisChar
        SET @position = @position + 1
    END -- We've gone past the length now

    -- Now we need to figure out and add the checksum character
    SET @checksum = @checksumTotal % 103
    IF @checksum = 0
        SET @finalArray = @finalArray + @spacechar
    ELSE
        -- Barcorde array assumes 0 as initial offset so we need to add 1 to checksum
        SET @finalArray = @finalArray + SUBSTRING(@asciiString, @checksum+1, 1)
    
    -- Now we append the stop character
    SET @finalArray = @finalArray + @stopchar

    -- The @final Array represents the barcode encoded string
    RETURN @finalArray

END
```