# code 128 barcode in c# wrong check digit for one barcode

Tags: c#, barcode, code128, check-digit

I have been using the code from [here](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/BarcodeStringBuilderExample.aspx) to convert three digit numbers to barcodes for scanning in the company I work for.
I have only found a problem with one barcode.  When it encodes "002" it outputs "Ì002 Î".  I have found that this will not scan with the space.  With much time searching and looking for what should be in that space and what scans.  I found that the barcode generator generator code from [here](https://racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/1d/code-128/) has the Â as the check character.

Now for my question How could I change the code to encode that correctly? Or,Is there another FREE code sample that I could implement to get the code 128 barcode?

I have it implemented like

```
MEKBarcodeLBL.Text = HazmatLabels.Classes.BarcodeConverter128.StringToBarcode(MEKScrapLBL.Text).PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!!!!

BarcodeConverter128.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace HazmatLabels.Classes
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Code 128
    /// Convert an input string to the equivilant string including start and stop characters.
    /// This object compresses the values to the shortest possible code 128 barcode format 
    /// </summary>
    public static class BarcodeConverter128
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts an input string to the equivilant string, that need to be produced using the 'Code 128' font.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">String to be encoded</param>
        /// <returns>Encoded string start/stop and checksum characters included</returns>
        public static string StringToBarcode(string value)
        {
            // Parameters : a string
            // Return     : a string which give the bar code when it is dispayed with CODE128.TTF font
            //           : an empty string if the supplied parameter is no good
            int charPos, minCharPos;
            int currentChar, checksum;
            bool isTableB = true, isValid = true;
            string returnValue = string.Empty;

            if (value.Length > 0)
            {

                // Check for valid characters
                for (int charCount = 0; charCount < value.Length; charCount++)
                {
                    //currentChar = char.GetNumericValue(value, charPos);
                    currentChar = (int)char.Parse(value.Substring(charCount, 1));
                    if (!(currentChar >= 32 && currentChar <= 126))
                    {
                        isValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Barcode is full of ascii characters, we can now process it
                if (isValid)
                {
                    charPos = 0;
                    while (charPos < value.Length)
                    {
                        if (isTableB)
                        {
                            // See if interesting to switch to table C
                            // yes for 4 digits at start or end, else if 6 digits
                            if (charPos == 0 || charPos + 4 == value.Length)
                                minCharPos = 4;
                            else
                                minCharPos = 6;


                            minCharPos = BarcodeConverter128.IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos);

                            if (minCharPos < 0)
                            {
                                // Choice table C
                                if (charPos == 0)
                                {
                                    // Starting with table C
                                    returnValue = ((char)205).ToString(); // char.ConvertFromUtf32(205);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Switch to table C
                                    returnValue = returnValue + ((char)199).ToString();
                                }
                                isTableB = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (charPos == 0)
                                {
                                    // Starting with table B
                                    returnValue = ((char)204).ToString(); // char.ConvertFromUtf32(204);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        if (!isTableB)
                        {
                            // We are on table C, try to process 2 digits
                            minCharPos = 2;
                            minCharPos = BarcodeConverter128.IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos);
                            if (minCharPos < 0) // OK for 2 digits, process it
                            {
                                currentChar = int.Parse(value.Substring(charPos, 2));
                                currentChar = currentChar < 95 ? currentChar + 32 : currentChar + 100;
                                returnValue = returnValue + ((char)currentChar).ToString();
                                charPos += 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // We haven't 2 digits, switch to table B
                                returnValue = returnValue + ((char)200).ToString();
                                isTableB = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isTableB)
                        {
                            // Process 1 digit with table B
                            returnValue = returnValue + value.Substring(charPos, 1);
                            charPos++;
                        }
                    }

                    // Calculation of the checksum
                    checksum = 0;
                    for (int loop = 0; loop < returnValue.Length; loop++)
                    {
                        currentChar = (int)char.Parse(returnValue.Substring(loop, 1));
                        currentChar = currentChar < 127 ? currentChar - 32 : currentChar - 100;
                        if (loop == 0)
                            checksum = currentChar;
                        else
                            checksum = (checksum + (loop * currentChar)) % 103;
                    }

                    // Calculation of the checksum ASCII code
                    checksum = checksum < 95 ? checksum + 32 : checksum + 100;
                    // Add the checksum and the STOP
                    returnValue = returnValue +
                        ((char)checksum).ToString() +
                        ((char)206).ToString();
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }


        private static int IsNumber(string InputValue, int CharPos, int MinCharPos)
        {
            // if the MinCharPos characters from CharPos are numeric, then MinCharPos = -1
            MinCharPos--;
            if (CharPos + MinCharPos < InputValue.Length)
            {
                while (MinCharPos >= 0)
                {
                    if ((int)char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1)) < 48
                        || (int)char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1)) > 57)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    MinCharPos--;
                }
            }
            return MinCharPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of code you have written? Or a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: does it need to be code 128? ive never had failings with 39

Comment: http://www.barcode-generator.org/ this one also does the code 128 check character for "002" as the Â.

Comment: try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14409/GenCode-A-Code-Barcode-Generator)

Comment: The M in MVCE stands for minimal

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what that meant and didn't know what code you were looking for.  This is the code I found to use for free and don't exactly understand the science of creating barcodes.

Comment: It looks like the string generated by the first set of code is specific to the font linked to at the site. The ASCII space is the expected checksum for the data - so it may be the font is generating invalid barcodes. The second set of code you have shown generated the actual values specified for [Code-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) - the final set of code should produce a Code-128 barcode from those values - have you tried that code.

Comment: But it is only the "002" that does not scan.  All the other barcodes it creates are correct.

Comment: Maybe you haven't generated another barcode that results in the same checksum (Code-128 value 0 - represented as space in the string). The second set of code correctly encodes as values 104 16 16 18 0 106 => 104=Code Set B 106=Stop  16='0' 18='2'  Checksum = (104 + 1*16 + 2*16 + 3*18) % 103 = 206%103 = 0. Value 0 is represented as space in the Font according to the Wiki page - so is valid

Comment: That is most likely correct PaulF.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community and I am having trouble getting the other code so that I can display the image that it makes.  How would I do that?

Comment: As you have now deleted the rendering code I can't test it for you ;-)

Comment: PaulF I have posted it in an answer below so that the first one is not as big.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the other code and I am not sure on how to implement it.

Code128Rendering.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace GenCode128
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for Code128Rendering.
        /// </summary>
        public static class Code128Rendering
        {

            #region Code patterns

            // in principle these rows should each have 6 elements
            // however, the last one -- STOP -- has 7. The cost of the
            // extra integers is trivial, and this lets the code flow
            // much more elegantly
            private static readonly int[,] cPatter

ns =
                       {
                        {2,1,2,2,2,2,0,0},  // 0
                        {2,2,2,1,2,2,0,0},  // 1
                        {2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0},  // 2
                        {1,2,1,2,2,3,0,0},  // 3
                        {1,2,1,3,2,2,0,0},  // 4
                        {1,3,1,2,2,2,0,0},  // 5
                        {1,2,2,2,1,3,0,0},  // 6
                        {1,2,2,3,1,2,0,0},  // 7
                        {1,3,2,2,1,2,0,0},  // 8
                        {2,2,1,2,1,3,0,0},  // 9
                        {2,2,1,3,1,2,0,0},  // 10
                        {2,3,1,2,1,2,0,0},  // 11
                        {1,1,2,2,3,2,0,0},  // 12
                        {1,2,2,1,3,2,0,0},  // 13
                        {1,2,2,2,3,1,0,0},  // 14
                        {1,1,3,2,2,2,0,0},  // 15
                        {1,2,3,1,2,2,0,0},  // 16
                        {1,2,3,2,2,1,0,0},  // 17
                        {2,2,3,2,1,1,0,0},  // 18
                        {2,2,1,1,3,2,0,0},  // 19
                        {2,2,1,2,3,1,0,0},  // 20
                        {2,1,3,2,1,2,0,0},  // 21
                        {2,2,3,1,1,2,0,0},  // 22
                        {3,1,2,1,3,1,0,0},  // 23
                        {3,1,1,2,2,2,0,0},  // 24
                        {3,2,1,1,2,2,0,0},  // 25
                        {3,2,1,2,2,1,0,0},  // 26
                        {3,1,2,2,1,2,0,0},  // 27
                        {3,2,2,1,1,2,0,0},  // 28
                        {3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0},  // 29
                        {2,1,2,1,2,3,0,0},  // 30
                        {2,1,2,3,2,1,0,0},  // 31
                        {2,3,2,1,2,1,0,0},  // 32
                        {1,1,1,3,2,3,0,0},  // 33
                        {1,3,1,1,2,3,0,0},  // 34
                        {1,3,1,3,2,1,0,0},  // 35
                        {1,1,2,3,1,3,0,0},  // 36
                        {1,3,2,1,1,3,0,0},  // 37
                        {1,3,2,3,1,1,0,0},  // 38
                        {2,1,1,3,1,3,0,0},  // 39
                        {2,3,1,1,1,3,0,0},  // 40
                        {2,3,1,3,1,1,0,0},  // 41
                        {1,1,2,1,3,3,0,0},  // 42
                        {1,1,2,3,3,1,0,0},  // 43
                        {1,3,2,1,3,1,0,0},  // 44
                        {1,1,3,1,2,3,0,0},  // 45
                        {1,1,3,3,2,1,0,0},  // 46
                        {1,3,3,1,2,1,0,0},  // 47
                        {3,1,3,1,2,1,0,0},  // 48
                        {2,1,1,3,3,1,0,0},  // 49
                        {2,3,1,1,3,1,0,0},  // 50
                        {2,1,3,1,1,3,0,0},  // 51
                        {2,1,3,3,1,1,0,0},  // 52
                        {2,1,3,1,3,1,0,0},  // 53
                        {3,1,1,1,2,3,0,0},  // 54
                        {3,1,1,3,2,1,0,0},  // 55
                        {3,3,1,1,2,1,0,0},  // 56
                        {3,1,2,1,1,3,0,0},  // 57
                        {3,1,2,3,1,1,0,0},  // 58
                        {3,3,2,1,1,1,0,0},  // 59
                        {3,1,4,1,1,1,0,0},  // 60
                        {2,2,1,4,1,1,0,0},  // 61
                        {4,3,1,1,1,1,0,0},  // 62
                        {1,1,1,2,2,4,0,0},  // 63
                        {1,1,1,4,2,2,0,0},  // 64
                        {1,2,1,1,2,4,0,0},  // 65
                        {1,2,1,4,2,1,0,0},  // 66
                        {1,4,1,1,2,2,0,0},  // 67
                        {1,4,1,2,2,1,0,0},  // 68
                        {1,1,2,2,1,4,0,0},  // 69
                        {1,1,2,4,1,2,0,0},  // 70
                        {1,2,2,1,1,4,0,0},  // 71
                        {1,2,2,4,1,1,0,0},  // 72
                        {1,4,2,1,1,2,0,0},  // 73
                        {1,4,2,2,1,1,0,0},  // 74
                        {2,4,1,2,1,1,0,0},  // 75
                        {2,2,1,1,1,4,0,0},  // 76
                        {4,1,3,1,1,1,0,0},  // 77
                        {2,4,1,1,1,2,0,0},  // 78
                        {1,3,4,1,1,1,0,0},  // 79
                        {1,1,1,2,4,2,0,0},  // 80
                        {1,2,1,1,4,2,0,0},  // 81
                        {1,2,1,2,4,1,0,0},  // 82
                        {1,1,4,2,1,2,0,0},  // 83
                        {1,2,4,1,1,2,0,0},  // 84
                        {1,2,4,2,1,1,0,0},  // 85
                        {4,1,1,2,1,2,0,0},  // 86
                        {4,2,1,1,1,2,0,0},  // 87
                        {4,2,1,2,1,1,0,0},  // 88
                        {2,1,2,1,4,1,0,0},  // 89
                        {2,1,4,1,2,1,0,0},  // 90
                        {4,1,2,1,2,1,0,0},  // 91
                        {1,1,1,1,4,3,0,0},  // 92
                        {1,1,1,3,4,1,0,0},  // 93
                        {1,3,1,1,4,1,0,0},  // 94
                        {1,1,4,1,1,3,0,0},  // 95
                        {1,1,4,3,1,1,0,0},  // 96
                        {4,1,1,1,1,3,0,0},  // 97
                        {4,1,1,3,1,1,0,0},  // 98
                        {1,1,3,1,4,1,0,0},  // 99
                        {1,1,4,1,3,1,0,0},  // 100
                        {3,1,1,1,4,1,0,0},  // 101
                        {4,1,1,1,3,1,0,0},  // 102
                        {2,1,1,4,1,2,0,0},  // 103
                        {2,1,1,2,1,4,0,0},  // 104
                        {2,1,1,2,3,2,0,0},  // 105
                        {2,3,3,1,1,1,2,0}   // 106
                     };

        #endregion Code patterns

        private const int cQuietWidth = 10;

        /// <summary>
        /// Make an image of a Code128 barcode for a given string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="InputData">Message to be encoded</param>
        /// <param name="BarWeight">Base thickness for bar width (1 or 2 works well)</param>
        /// <param name="AddQuietZone">Add required horiz margins (use if output is tight)</param>
        /// <returns>An Image of the Code128 barcode representing the message</returns>
        public static Image MakeBarcodeImage(string InputData, int BarWeight, bool AddQuietZone)
        {
            // get the Code128 codes to represent the message
            Code128Content content = new Code128Content(InputData);
            int[] codes = content.Codes;

            int width, height;
            width = ((codes.Length - 3) * 11 + 35) * BarWeight;
            height = Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToSingle(width) * .15F));

            if (AddQuietZone)
            {
                width += 2 * cQuietWidth * BarWeight;  // on both sides
            }

            // get surface to draw on
            Image myimg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(myimg))
            {

                // set to white so we don't have to fill the spaces with white
                gr.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);

                // skip quiet zone
                int cursor = AddQuietZone ? cQuietWidth * BarWeight : 0;

                for (int codeidx = 0; codeidx < codes.Length; codeidx++)
                {
                    int code = codes[codeidx];

                    // take the bars two at a time: a black and a white
                    for (int bar = 0; bar < 8; bar += 2)
                    {
                        int barwidth = cPatterns[code, bar] * BarWeight;
                        int spcwidth = cPatterns[code, bar + 1] * BarWeight;

                        // if width is zero, don't try to draw it
                        if (barwidth > 0)
                        {
                            gr.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, cursor, 0, barwidth, height);
                        }

                        // note that we never need to draw the space, since we 
                        // initialized the graphics to all white

                        // advance cursor beyond this pair
                        cursor += (barwidth + spcwidth);
                    }
                }
            }

            return myimg;

        }

    }
}
```

Code128Content.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace GenCode128
{
    public enum CodeSet
    {
        CodeA
       , CodeB
        // ,CodeC   // not supported
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represent the set of code values to be output into barcode form
    /// </summary>
    public class Code128Content
    {
        private int[] mCodeList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create content based on a string of ASCII data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="AsciiData">the string that should be represented</param>
        public Code128Content(string AsciiData)
        {
            mCodeList = StringToCode128(AsciiData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides the Code128 code values representing the object's string
        /// </summary>
        public int[] Codes
        {
            get
            {
                return mCodeList;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transform the string into integers representing the Code128 codes
        /// necessary to represent it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="AsciiData">String to be encoded</param>
        /// <returns>Code128 representation</returns>
        private int[] StringToCode128(string AsciiData)
        {
            // turn the string into ascii byte data
            byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AsciiData);

            // decide which codeset to start with
            Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed csa1 = asciiBytes.Length > 0 ? Code128Code.CodesetAllowedForChar(asciiBytes[0]) : Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeAorB;
            Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed csa2 = asciiBytes.Length > 0 ? Code128Code.CodesetAllowedForChar(asciiBytes[1]) : Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeAorB;
            CodeSet currcs = GetBestStartSet(csa1, csa2);

            // set up the beginning of the barcode
            System.Collections.ArrayList codes = new System.Collections.ArrayList(asciiBytes.Length + 3); // assume no codeset changes, account for start, checksum, and stop
            codes.Add(Code128Code.StartCodeForCodeSet(currcs));

            // add the codes for each character in the string
            for (int i = 0; i < asciiBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                int thischar = asciiBytes[i];
                int nextchar = asciiBytes.Length > (i + 1) ? asciiBytes[i + 1] : -1;

                codes.AddRange(Code128Code.CodesForChar(thischar, nextchar, ref currcs));
            }

            // calculate the check digit
            int checksum = (int)(codes[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < codes.Count; i++)
            {
                checksum += i * (int)(codes[i]);
            }
            codes.Add(checksum % 103);

            codes.Add(Code128Code.StopCode());

            int[] result = codes.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[];
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the best starting code set based on the the first two 
        /// characters of the string to be encoded
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="csa1">First character of input string</param>
        /// <param name="csa2">Second character of input string</param>
        /// <returns>The codeset determined to be best to start with</returns>
        private CodeSet GetBestStartSet(Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed csa1, Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed csa2)
        {
            int vote = 0;

            vote += (csa1 == Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeA) ? 1 : 0;
            vote += (csa1 == Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeB) ? -1 : 0;
            vote += (csa2 == Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeA) ? 1 : 0;
            vote += (csa2 == Code128Code.CodeSetAllowed.CodeB) ? -1 : 0;

            return (vote > 0) ? CodeSet.CodeA : CodeSet.CodeB;   // ties go to codeB due to my own prejudices
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static tools for determining codes for individual characters in the content
    /// </summary>
    public static class Code128Code
    {
        #region Constants

        private const int cSHIFT = 98;
        private const int cCODEA = 101;
        private const int cCODEB = 100;

        private const int cSTARTA = 103;
        private const int cSTARTB = 104;
        private const int cSTOP = 106;

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Code128 code value(s) to represent an ASCII character, with 
        /// optional look-ahead for length optimization
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="CharAscii">The ASCII value of the character to translate</param>
        /// <param name="LookAheadAscii">The next character in sequence (or -1 if none)</param>
        /// <param name="CurrCodeSet">The current codeset, that the returned codes need to follow;
        /// if the returned codes change that, then this value will be changed to reflect it</param>
        /// <returns>An array of integers representing the codes that need to be output to produce the 
        /// given character</returns>
        public static int[] CodesForChar(int CharAscii, int LookAheadAscii, ref CodeSet CurrCodeSet)
        {
            int[] result;
            int shifter = -1;

            if (!CharCompatibleWithCodeset(CharAscii, CurrCodeSet))
            {
                // if we have a lookahead character AND if the next character is ALSO not compatible
                if ((LookAheadAscii != -1) && !CharCompatibleWithCodeset(LookAheadAscii, CurrCodeSet))
                {
                    // we need to switch code sets
                    switch (CurrCodeSet)
                    {
                        case CodeSet.CodeA:
                            shifter = cCODEB;
                            CurrCodeSet = CodeSet.CodeB;
                            break;
                        case CodeSet.CodeB:
                            shifter = cCODEA;
                            CurrCodeSet = CodeSet.CodeA;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // no need to switch code sets, a temporary SHIFT will suffice
                    shifter = cSHIFT;
                }
            }

            if (shifter != -1)
            {
                result = new int[2];
                result[0] = shifter;
                result[1] = CodeValueForChar(CharAscii);
            }
            else
            {
                result = new int[1];
                result[0] = CodeValueForChar(CharAscii);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tells us which codesets a given character value is allowed in
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="CharAscii">ASCII value of character to look at</param>
        /// <returns>Which codeset(s) can be used to represent this character</returns>
        public static CodeSetAllowed CodesetAllowedForChar(int CharAscii)
        {
            if (CharAscii >= 32 && CharAscii <= 95)
            {
                return CodeSetAllowed.CodeAorB;
            }
            else
            {
                return (CharAscii < 32) ? CodeSetAllowed.CodeA : CodeSetAllowed.CodeB;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determine if a character can be represented in a given codeset
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="CharAscii">character to check for</param>
        /// <param name="currcs">codeset context to test</param>
        /// <returns>true if the codeset contains a representation for the ASCII character</returns>
        public static bool CharCompatibleWithCodeset(int CharAscii, CodeSet currcs)
        {
            CodeSetAllowed csa = CodesetAllowedForChar(CharAscii);
            return csa == CodeSetAllowed.CodeAorB
                     || (csa == CodeSetAllowed.CodeA && currcs == CodeSet.CodeA)
                     || (csa == CodeSetAllowed.CodeB && currcs == CodeSet.CodeB);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the integer code128 code value for a character (assuming the appropriate code set)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="CharAscii">character to convert</param>
        /// <returns>code128 symbol value for the character</returns>
        public static int CodeValueForChar(int CharAscii)
        {
            return (CharAscii >= 32) ? CharAscii - 32 : CharAscii + 64;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the appropriate START code depending on the codeset we want to be in
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cs">The codeset you want to start in</param>
        /// <returns>The code128 code to start a barcode in that codeset</returns>
        public static int StartCodeForCodeSet(CodeSet cs)
        {
            return cs == CodeSet.CodeA ? cSTARTA : cSTARTB;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the Code128 stop code
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>the stop code</returns>
        public static int StopCode()
        {
            return cSTOP;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates which code sets can represent a character -- CodeA, CodeB, or either
        /// </summary>
        public enum CodeSetAllowed
        {
            CodeA,
            CodeB,
            CodeAorB
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked the rendering code above in a WPF application & it does create a scannable image returning "002" - are you using WPF?

Comment: I am using asp.net.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of much help there - but this link may help https://forums.asp.net/t/1220818.aspx or this one https://forums.asp.net/t/1822833.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview  or other links here https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=gCoLWv6OA8n5avani6gL&q=how+to+display+system.drawing.image+in+image+control+in+asp.net&oq=asp.net+display+System.Drawing.Image&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i30k1j0i8i30k1.602726.604134.0.608997.8.8.0.0.0.0.164.669.7j1.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.665...0i8i7i30k1.0.S9PT7OivqpA